# Computing the mean of a column using number

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am computing the mean of a column1 from a dataframe:

```
df[1].mean
```

or

```
df[:, 1].mean
```

It showed error:

```
'in get_loc
raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 1'
```

Anyone know how I could fix it? (the mean should avoid taking header row into account)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `df.iloc[:, 1].mean()` instead of `df[:, 1].mean()`

also note that you have to call the `mean` function by adding parentheses `mean()`

**Example**

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd 
   ...: import numpy as np 
   ...:  
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(3,3))) 
   ...: print(df)                                                                                                                                            
   0  1  2
0  3  9  2
1  0  0  5
2  8  3  0

In [2]: df.iloc[:,1].mean()                                                                                                                                  
Out[2]: 4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work (except missing `()` for `mean`) if the column name is really in numeric format.  For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]})

df[1].mean()


Output:

2.0
```

One possibility of such error is that your column name is actually a character (1-letter string).  For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]})

df[1].mean()

Output:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-0fbd35b7b19f> in <module>
----> 1 df[1].mean()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3022             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3023                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3024             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3025             if is_integer(indexer):
   3026                 indexer = [indexer]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3083 
   3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 1
```

In this case, you should enclose the `1` in a pair of parenthesis:

```
df['1'].mean()

Output:

2.0
```